# Features Missing After Windows Réinstallation on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: windows-8.1, reinstall

guys.  Some time ago I accidentally deleted my windows O. S.  and installed Linux.  Today I downloaded a new copy of Windows 8.1 and reinstalled it on my Toshiba Satellite C55t-b5230.  However,  I noticed that the settings are different,  certain functions are no longer available as well.  Is there a way for me to to get back the settings,  features and specialities I used to have on it?

Comment: Can you be specific.  Which features are missing?

Comment: Well,  the brightness keys no longer work,  there is no shut do,  hibernate,  sleep estat

Comment: *sleep restart options unless I sign out.  Also there was a Toshiba settings app,  that's gone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description of your computer is at:

http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/c50/C55T-B5230

Drivers and software and other support information is at:

http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200008281

The above site will enable you to download and install your missing features

I am a Satellite owner, and the support site works well for the sort of thing you are trying to do. Best of luck!

Comment: Thnx man... They're all there.